# Grabbing the latest record without using a subquery

Tags: mysql

Here is the table set up

```
tbl_fruit
____________________
id | title  | round

1 | bananas | 0

2 | apples | 1

3 | orange | 1

4 | pear | 0
```

I would like to get the latest added row of rounded fruit in a single query without using a subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_fruit 
WHERE round = 1 AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_fruit WHERE round = 1);
```

From my understanding sub queries can be slow and I would like to convert the above query.  Any suggestions?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_fruit WHERE round =1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: The slowness of subqueries is situationally dependent. Mihai's solution above is the most standard form of the kind of query you are asking for, but there are cases where a subquery could be faster than an `ORDER BY x LIMIT y`. _This is not one of them._

Comment: if id is indexed (and it probably is) there's nothing wrong with using a subquery. if it is not index, it will be slow regardless of the query you're using. an index on round would help too.

Comment: If your intention is to find only the latest row, you can use ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;